# How to create dummy or mocked WCF service to use original WCF service is not available?

Tags: wcf, mocking

My issue it regarding creating a dummy WCF service which can be used at development side, when the REAL WCF service is not available or is down.

In my current assignment, the issue is that the web hosted WCF service from client is not always available for developer side. This hampers the development work as we are not able to verify/unit test the client side code.

Any solutions in sight? I have been searching /reading about mocking wcf with different available mocking frameworks, but still not clear about the right way.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Without talking about frameworks - to call your srevice, you create client (proxy) instance, right?

You can move its generation to separate method, which will return your mock (injected by DI, injected by setter property in Unit test,. . .).